# How to have a nullable DateTime property in gRPC .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using gRPC to write a method and give it to another microservice but I do not know how to generate a nullable DateTime property in protobuf and fill it with a data that I get from AppService!
The final property that I need is like below:

```
public class MyClass{
   public DateTime? MyDateTime {get;set;}
}
```

And also there is no variable type as a DateTime in protobuf.

I'm expecting to set a nullable DateTime property in my proto file and after that fill it with a DataTime that I get from another service in gRPCService.

Comment: [Dates and times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#dates-and-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by using:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```

In proto file and also in the current file the message property should be:

```
message MyTestDto{
    google.protobuf.Timestamp MyTimestamp = 1;
}
```

After doing all of these steps in the GrpcService I used this C# code to convert timestamp to DateTime:

```
Timestamp.FromDateTimeOffset(x.CvCardFa.MyTimestamp.Value.ToLocalTime())
```